# showing values with multiple sliders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code after I abandoned my previous attempt at getting something like this to work via progressbars.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Slider Bars</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
    .ui-slider-handle .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default  {
        background: url(img/marker.png) top left no-repeat;
        height:41px;
        width:50px;
        position:absolute;
        top:-25px;
        padding:0;
        border:none;
        margin-left:-1.7em;
    }


    .ui-widget-content {
        background-color: #666262;
        -webkit-background-size: 100px 100px;
        -moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
        background-size: 100px 100px;         
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                            color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                            color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)),
                            color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                            to(transparent));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                            transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                            transparent 75%, transparent);            
        height: 25px;
        width: 390px;
        margin:10px 0;         
        -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px #000 inset, 0 1px 0 #444;  
        border:0;   
    }

  .ui-widget-header {
        background-color: #aa7a64;
    -webkit-background-size: 100px 100px;
    -moz-background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-size: 100px 100px;         
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom,
                        color-stop(.25, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15)), color-stop(.25, transparent),
                        color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15)),
                        color-stop(.75, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15)), color-stop(.75, transparent),
                        to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15) 50%, rgba(134, 0, 0, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%,
                        transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%,
                        transparent 75%, transparent);
    height:25px;
    padding:0!important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) inset;
    }
.darker {
    background-color: #85483e; 
}

    #revAttain {
        margin:125px 0 0 0;
    }

    #revAttain span {
        width:590px;
        height:25px;
        margin:10px 0;
        display:block;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#revAttain > span" ).each(function() {

        var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
        $( this ).empty().slider({
        value: value,
        range:"min",
        orientation: "horizontal",
        animate: true,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).find('a').html('<span>' + value + '</span');
        }
     });
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="revAttain">
        <span>25</span><br />
        <span>43</span><br />
        <span>55</span><br />
        <span>33</span><br />
        <span>40</span><br />
        <span>45</span><br />
        <span>70</span>
    </div>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using the multiple sliders example on the jquery UI page and am unable to get the value of the sliding bars width value into the slider handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
$( "#revAttain > span" ).each(function() {

    var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
    $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range:"min",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find('a').html('<span>' + value + '</span');
    }
 });
```

});

with

```
$( "#revAttain > span" ).each(function() {

    var value = parseInt( $( this ).text(), 10 );
    $( this ).empty().slider({
    value: value,
    range:"min",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    animate: true,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var newValue = $(this).slider("option","value");
        $(this).find('a').html('<span>' + newValue + '</span');

    }


 });

        $(this).find('a').html('<span>' + value + '</span');
 });
```

Comment: very nice...the only problem is that it doesn't show up immediately on the page.

Comment: Thank you...I had added something after the line with var value but I like your solution better. Thank you so much for your help.